# Media Player Classic on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, media-player-classic

I know that there are many great video players for Linux but I need MPC-HC for the specific reason that I can hide the seek bar by pressing Ctrl+1.

Could MPC-HC be compiled and used under Debian Linux?

Also if there is a player under Linux that can allow the seek bar the be hidden used a shortcut, I am open to use it.

Comment: As opposed to using a player that doesn't even show the seek bar?

Comment: No, I need the option to hide it, btw is there such a player, please point me to one.

Comment: Have you tried loading MPC under Wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need MPC-HC for the specific reason that I can hide the seek bar by pressing Ctrl+1.

It sounds like you need a player which can hide its seek bar by pressing Ctrl+1. That, on its own, is not a reason to need MPC-HC specifically.

- In gnome-mplayer, the seek bar can be displayed or hidden using <kbd>c</kbd> but you can change this to <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> via gnome-mplayer's settings window.
- In mpv, the seek bar is always floating and only visible when you move the mouse. You can bind <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> to the seek bar's visibility via input.conf:

  ```
  Ctrl+1 script-message osc-visibility never
  Ctrl+2 script-message osc-visibility always
  ```
- In VLC, you can toggle the seek bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> (in windowed mode) or <kbd>i</kbd> (fullscreen).
- In gnome-mpv, you can toggle the seek bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>. You can also switch the bar to 'floating' mode, which does not occupy permanent space and disappears when unused.